# Mocking Async Task

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I have the following situation in my unit tests using Moq on .NET 4.0 using Microsoft BCL

```
Task<MyClass> mockTask = new Task<MyClass>(() => new MyClass());

uploadHelper.Setup().Returns(mockTask);

Task.WaitAll(mockTask);
```

The problem that I am facing is that Task.WaitAll(mockTask) simply blocks and never returns.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit**
Note that mockTask is async here in my context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed solutions have one problem - the task may be over by the time `Returns` is called.
That means your unit test exhibits a different async semantics than your real code.  Is that what you want?

If you truly want to capture the async nature of the tested code you must not use the `Returns` method with a value.

Instead use the Returns overload accepting a function. Something like this:

```
uploadHelper.Setup().Returns(() => Task.Run(() => new MyClass()));
```

That way you can be certain to exercise async execution path.

Answer (score 15):

Your task is not started !

Just use:

```
 Task<MyClass> mockTask = Task.FromResult(new MyClass());
```

Alternatively, this works as well:

```
Task<MyClass> mockTask = new Task<MyClass>(() => new MyClass());
mockTask.Start();
```

Comment: I had to use TaskEx.FromResult as I am on .Net 4.0

Comment: The alternate way gives me "Start may not be called on a promise-style task" as it is async task. I did not mention it in my post. I have updated my post

Comment: Task.FromResult is a better option, since it doesn't start a new thread. Calling a constructor for Task will schedule a thread to run on the ThreadPool, which is going to take longer. Although this is for a test, and performance isn't a huge deal, you'd want to avoid doing this a lot if you have many async methods to test. Also, it's declarative, which helps with readability.

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new MyClass());
```